# only to loop through the table heading once when add button is pressed, react js

Tags: reactjs

Here when I press the plus button, then heading also gets printed...how do i loop it so that heading only prints once for the page. Initially the page needs to be blank, and heading and "hello this is a new row!" should appear on the first click and only "hello this is a new row!" appear on ssecond and every other click after that

https://codesandbox.io/s/sad-shtern-pu66k

```
import React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";

const styles = {
  fontFamily: "sans-serif",
  textAlign: "left"
};

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      rows: []
    };
  }

  handleAddRow = () => {
    this.setState((prevState, props) => {
      const row1 = { content: "heading" };
      const row = { content: "hello this is a new row!" };
      return { rows: [...prevState.rows, row1, row] };
    });
  };

  handleRemoveRow = () => {
    this.setState((prevState, props) => {
      return { rows: prevState.rows.slice(1) };
    });
  };

  render() {
    console.log(this.state);
    return (
      <div style={styles}>
        <table>
          <tbody>
            {this.state.rows.map(row => (
              <tr>
                <td>{row.content}</td>
              </tr>
            ))}
            <tr>
              <td className="" onClick={this.handleAddRow}>
                (+)
              </td>
              {Boolean(this.state.rows.length) && (
                <td onClick={this.handleRemoveRow}>(-)</td>
              )}
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your add handle row method should look like this

```
handleAddRow = () => {
this.setState((prevState, props) => {
  const row1 = { content: "heading" };
  const row = { content: "hello this is a new row!" };
  return { rows: [...prevState.rows, row] };
});
```

};

and the constructor needs to be this

```
constructor(props) {
super(props);
this.state = {
  rows: ["Header"]
}
```

Just updated sandbox to your needs
https://codesandbox.io/s/objective-browser-se11n

Okay

1. this.state.rows starts empty because you want nothing to be displayed in the beginning
2. Every time the plus button is clicked we add something so handleAddRow is called
3. Every time handleAdd row is called it checks the length of this.state.rows, if the state is empty it prepares a variable add the header, if not it prepares a variable to add the row
4. It adds the prepared variable to this.state through a this.setState method

let me know if this isn't clear enough

Comment: This didnt work for me, could you please demonstrate it on code sandbox

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/funny-blackburn-e1ovf  I had made some changes.. here I am trying to display the input boxes and table heading as part of one table but the alightment is a bit off, can you suggest anything for it. also when i click minus to delete, I am trying to delete the current row and not the heading

Comment: Deleting the current row is pretty straightforward. It's all about the Array.slice method you're currently doing array.slice(1) which slices to the 1st index. Look at the docs for array.slice I just don't remember off the top of my head the current implementation

As far as alignment goes it just depends how professional you need this. I'd consider making this into a table, if not just add margin or padding